# Independent scroll parent and child div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

There are two scrollable div as in the below image.

[scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtcLf.png)

The Yellow Div Css:

```
 #workbench-container #workbench md-content .folder .folder-notes {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%; 
 }
```

And the Parent scroll bar is ng-scrollable directive.

```
<div ng-scrollable="{scrollX:'none',scrollY:'right'}" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;">
```

**Can you suggest to scroll two div contents independently.**

I tried to add to a controller the following

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.mydiv')).bind( 'mousewheel', function ( e ) {
           var event = e.originalEvent;
           var d = event.wheelDelta || -event.detail;
           this.scrollTop += ( d < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
           e.preventDefault();
        });
```

When scroll in child div(yellow box) the parent scroll is also scrolling together. Need to scroll only the div in which mouse is placed.?

Answer (score 0):

Make two child instead of one.

Make both child scrolls, basicly can do it with the same css.
Can put the child in a table of the parent `<tr><td><child1></child1></td><td><cdhild2></child2></td></tr>`

And put the childs in your scroll div of your parent.